# Table style view and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a prbolem with AngularJS and table view. I have a JSON-data like this (for example):

```
{
    { name: 'Item #1', description: 'Item #1 description' },
    { name: 'Item #2', description: 'Item #2 description' },
    { name: 'Item #3', description: 'Item #3 description' }
}
```

I want to show this data in a table style, like Amazon. It's a table with some columns and rows (columns count is dynamic value). I can use 'data-ng-repeat', but how I can put only 3 or 5 (for example) elements in one row, and next 3 or 5 elements in the next row. How I can do it?

I use Bootstrap. I can view data as list:

```
<div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" data-ng-controller="itemsController">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" data-ng-repeat="item in items">
            <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
            <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But I want to view 3 items in one row. Good example is [Amazon style](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_283155_nr_n_0?rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A1&bbn=1000&ie=UTF8&qid=1405440975&rnid=1000).

Comment: Please provide more details including what you tried and the expected resultant html

Comment: First message was edited. Maybe I can solve my task with ng-If directive?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a custom table directive that I cooked up, feel free to try it out. Here is the sample plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/gYeLBb5r8VZPW8m6lhlE?p=preview

It's usage is:

`<my-table items="someArrayOfObjects"></my-table>`

It's a rough example with no real css, but it could be a starting point for what you want. It creates a table, creating the column headers based on the key values of the first object in the array (this assumes all your objects have the same key values). It also limits the number of items shown per page, and allows you to navigate from one page to the next and back. You could consider adding some more stylish pagination, like I said I more or less just implemented the logic.

Anyway, hope this helps!

Comment: I find solution for creating tables. It's a [ng-Grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/). But how I can view my items in this grid? The main problem is to divide my array and put his parts (with custom length) in rows using AngularJS or clean JS.

Comment: @user3619948 ah nice! That looks like a pretty good solution and actively developed. I am not familiar with ngGrid, I would suggest reading their documentation.